# MAUI: How to use device notification area

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I need to know how to implement functionality that uses device notification area even when device is in background. Messengers usually use this with ongoing calls.

I'll give example with AIMP player:

[image]

**NB:** I found out that you can implement this in *Android* with *Foreground Services*, but I need same functionality on **IOS** (and hopefully Windows)

Comment: As you said, it's the notification area, just invoke the api about sending the notification for your app.

Comment: My question in short was "how to in iOS" (and windows)

Comment: Did you check the [official document about the notification in the xamarin ios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/local-notifications-in-ios)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a service for this. A very popular one is Firebase from Google.

Here is a blog where it's implemented for .netMaui: https://www.andreasnesheim.no/push-notifications-in-net-maui-with-firebase/

Another option: a video from Gerald Versluis about it but with Xamarin: https://youtube.com/watch?v=VI1wgekz5ZM&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE (Android)

https://youtube.com/watch?v=GNBuaAB8nR8&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE (iOS)

I would prefer the blogpost.

Check out his channel. He also wants to make a video for .netMaui in the future.